# TFS Build doesn't download missing NuGet packages

Tags: .net, tfs, tfsbuild

I've been trying to setup my build server (Team Foundation Service) to automatically download 3rd party libraries and successfully build, but I don't know how to do this.

Is there a way ?

Comment: IMHO, that's a bad idea to do that. Shouldn't you know ahead of time which libraries your build runs with?

Comment: @JohnSaunders wouldn't that mean checking in the packages folder instead?

Comment: @stuartdotnet: yes, why is that a problem? If you don't use NuGet, don't you check in the `lib` folder or equivalent folder containing external dependencies?

Comment: @JohnSaunders that's fine, just wanted to confirm that was the alternative action.

Answer (score 8):

you need to enable package restore for the solution you want to build on the build machine. This is at least what I did to get NuGet to work with Team build.
Here's a link about package restore and how to use it during build
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages

Comment: In NuGet 2.7, you no longer have to enable it. It's on by default. http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.7

Answer (score 3):

To build upon what John Korsnes says above in his comment (because that alone wasn't enough to resolve my issue), from NuGet 2.7 you don't need to explicitly enable package restore as it is on by default. For my project I was getting missing references (notably "The type or namespace name 'Optimization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'").

The resolution to the problem was to go to Source Control Explorer and **delete the \packages folder**. I checked in the change and queued up another build. This took a while as the build server downloaded the packages, but the build completed successfully.